# Vertically align inline list items

Tags: html, css

The red `check-counter` floats right as expected but fail to remain vertically aligned when the screen shrinks, How can it remain vertically aligned regardless of how many lines the text in the `check-label` takes up? Thanks

[image]

```css
li {

  list-style-type: none;

}

div.container {

  padding: 0.25em;

}

.list-item {

  margin: 0.5em;

}

.checks-row li {

  vertical-align: middle;

  display: inline-block;

}

.check-image {

  width: 3.5em;

}

.check-filter, .check-counter {

  color: red;

}

.checks-row .check-counter {

  float: right;

}
```

```html
<template name="checks">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="list-item">
      {{#each values}}
      <ul class="checks-row" data-key={{this.key}}>
        {{#if imageExist this.image}}
        <li class="check-image">
          <img src="/{{this.image}}">
        </li>
        {{/if}}
        <li class="check-label">{{{this.label}}}</li>
        <li class="check-counter">{{this.counter}}</li>
        <hr>
      </ul>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A great way to do this is jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use **floating property** and some **width to counter part**, then it will work. Why don't you use some **calc()** style property value/attribute there?

[**Check this fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/9xr8urz1/5/)

HTML for example purpose

```
<ul>

    <li class="check-label">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born</li>
    <li class="check-counter">1</li>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

</ul>

<ul>

    <li class="check-label">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born</li>
    <li class="check-counter">2</li>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

</ul>
```

**Your CSS will be**

```
ul{
  list-style:none;
  background:#FFFFFF;
  width:300px;
  padding:10px;
  margin:0px;
  border-bottom:solid 1px #CCCCCC;
}

ul li{
  margin:0px;
}

ul li.check-label{
  float:left;
  width:calc(100% - 50px); 
}

ul li.check-counter{
  width:50px;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  color:red
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
 }

 .clearfix:after {
   clear: both; 
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this code is that it did not account for when the image is missing as in `{{#if imageExist this.image}}`

Comment: for valid html `div` is not allowed as direct child of `ul`